# Implementation options to consume SDL 8.5 Content Service in Java webapplication:

Tags: web8.5, microservices, discovery-service, cil, cis

We have java web application fetching Tridion content from Broker DB + Files System using CD APIs. We are planning to move to SDL web 8.5 content service and have below queries on same:

1) What are the different implementation options we have on web application end to consume same Tridion content now using SDL 8.5 content service?

2) Is it possible that the same existing web application code can be reused or it will be a completed re-code of the web application from scratch?

3)Is it mandatory to install the Discovery service here in this case because we are not using Topology manager (using legacy publishing Targets to publish items)? Is it possible to use content service without installing Discovery service through a java web application?

4) what is the exact installation package name for the same to be used for installation.

Additional details below:

SDL Web 8.5 version in use at present.
Java Web Application using In-process APIs. Its Not a web form based application
TCDL tags not in use and DCP are fetched in application code using Broker Query APIs

[image: Approach to consume Content service]

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a few more details? What is your current version of Tridion?, Is it a web form based application?, How your DCP and Component Link resolver are handled in your web app?, Are you using any tcdl tags on your web application?

Comment: @Velmurugan - Additional details added in the Question

Answer (score 3):

1. Your web application uses a client library (think of it as a "SDK") which talks to the webservices. The Web Application and the Web Services can scale independently of each other. You don't need licensing on the web application, making your auto-scaling a reality if you really want to. [This graph](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-599A7B77-49A5-41E0-8AD9-1FAF3F25D6E4) looks scary, but it's only for a minute until you realize it shows *everything* in Tridion. If you narrow it down to the Content Service part, you'll see it's actually not that complicated.
2. Using the Content Interaction Libraries "CIL" should give you a nearly 100% compatible API from a web application point of view. The CIL basically maps the old API to the REST API, and deals with caching, OAUTH, etc for you. Give it a try, it's quite easy to move from "old" to "new". Exception to this is if you have some "creative" work arounds like direct queries to the database, which would obviously not work anymore.
3. The microservices architecture requires the discovery service always, even if you don't use Topology Manager. This is because the services themselves will use discovery to figure out where the other services are and some of their own configuration.
4. Not sure what you mean with "installation package name". I would look at documentation [like this one](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-8789A353-267D-4466-9A6D-4CF6709E4E88) or installation help scripts like [the one I wrote myself](https://github.com/NunoLinhares/Web-8.5-Quick-Install/).

Comment: Thanks Nuno for sharing valuable details,I have below queries.
1)So for able to think two possible options to consume Content Service from a Java WebApp, Diagram for same attached above. Any comments on same ?
2)Option1 do not need Tridion license on WebApplication Server. Option2 needs Tridion license on Web application server. Is it true ?
3)Option1 worked without installing Discovery service. Option2 mandatory needs Discovery service to be installed because CIL client APIs are designed in such a way that they can not interact directly with content service. Is it correct ? Thanks

Comment: Neither of those options needs a license on the application server, as they both call the Content Service REST endpoint. The server where the Content Service runs needs a license. IIRC, calling the REST API directly is not supported, so it's not a real option (and it's not really documented either). Yes, CIL needs Discovery.